Is it necessary to shutdown the executor returned by Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()?
Project loom introduced a virtual thread executor service Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() which creates a new Virtual Thread (VT) every time we submit a task.
I have a couple of questions regarding it:

Java is not pooling anything and is creating a new VT for each task. is it necessary to shutdown the virtual thread pool? If so, what does it do internally?
if the shutdown is required, then how do I clean VTs that are created using thread factory threadFactory.newThread()

I have gone through Virtual Thread JEP, and it doesn't seem to mention anything about this topic.

You need to shut down if you want to be sure the executor service doesn't accept new tasks, and if you want to be able to await completion of all previously submitted tasks.
And given virtual threads are always daemon threads, awaiting termination is required if you want to be certain your tasks have all finished before you exit the application.
So, if you don't care if the tasks submitted to a virtual-thread executor service have completed before JVM exit, then you don't need to shut it down, but otherwise you really do need to shut down and await termination.
There is nothing special to do to clean up virtual threads. Once they end, they will be gone.

How do I clean up threads if I am using ThreadFactory? For some reason, I am creating VT using the factory and decorating it before calling the thread.

@GovindaSakhare Unless you're doing something weird in your thread factory, you don't need to do anything to clean up the thread. Otherwise you really should ask a separate question about that and provide a [mre] that shows your thread factory and clearly explain your concern.

But that might not be required if the implementation makes use of try-with-resources or any other way to ensure that the resource is closed. Isn't that the purpose of extending the AutoCloseable for ExecutorService itself?

@Naman Though true, in my experience, a lot of usages of executor service do not lend themselves to use try-with-resources, and are more generally shut down in some final cleanup action (e.g. as part of the application shut down). That said, I haven't worked that much with the Java 21 features, and I had entirely missed that it now has a close() method (since Java 19) that performs the shut down and await.

FYI, the OpenJDK implementation of close is similar to the boilerplate code given in the Javadoc of ExecutorService but with a timeout of 1 day.

Adding to the other answer, if you refer to the example shared in the JEP itself, an ideal way to implement using such an ExecutorService would be to enclose it within try with resources statement in which case the shutdown and waits are implicitly taken care of :
try (var executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) {
    IntStream.range(0, 10_000).forEach(i -> {
        executor.submit(() -> {
            Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
            return i;
        });
    });
}  // executor.close() is called implicitly, and waits

This holds also due to the change within the scope of the Second Preview of the JEP to make ExecutorService extend AutoCloseable exposing the single abstract method close for which

The default implementation invokes shutdown() and waits for tasks to
complete execution with awaitTermination.

Additionally, developers are not supposed to pool virtual threads, so you need not bother about cleaning them either. IMHO, most of this would have been implemented considering that they reduce the effort of implementing and maintaining applications using the feature.

Please note that this approach blocks the main thread until the virtual thread has completed
